# How to mock an IEnumerable that needs to be casted via LINQ (by .Cast<T>)?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, ienumerable

I have to deal with a third-party legacy interface that extends `IEnumerable`:

```cs
public interface IFoo : IEnumerable
{
    public IBar this[int index] { get; }
    public int Count { get; }
}
```

In my code I do the following:

```cs
IFoo foo;
foo.Cast<IBar>().Select( // do something...
```

During unit testing, I have to mock the interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar` (via FakeItEasy):

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var enumerator = A.Fake<IEnumerator>();
    A.CallTo(() => enumerator.MoveNext()).ReturnsNextFromSequence(false, true);

    var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>();
    var bar = A.Fake<IBar>();

    A.CallTo(() => foo.Count).Returns(1);
    A.CallTo(() => foo.GetEnumerator()).Returns(enumerator);
    A.CallTo(() => foo[An<int>.Ignored]).Returns(bar);

    _output.WriteLine(foo.Count); // 1
    _output.WriteLine(foo[0]);    // Faked IBar

    _output.WriteLine(foo.Cast<IBar>().ToList().Count); // 0
    _output.WriteLine(foo.Cast<IBar>().ToList()[0]);    // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
}
```

I also tried the following option, but without success:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>();
    var bar = A.Fake<IBar>();
    var barList = new List<IBar> {bar};

    A.CallTo(() => foo.Count).Returns(barList.Count);
    A.CallTo(() => foo.GetEnumerator()).Returns(barList.GetEnumerator());
    A.CallTo(() => foo[An<int>.Ignored]).Returns(bar);

    _output.WriteLine(foo.Count); // 1
    _output.WriteLine(foo[0]);    // Faked IBar

    _output.WriteLine(foo.Cast<IBar>().ToList().Count); // 0
    _output.WriteLine(foo.Cast<IBar>().ToList()[0]);    // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Why is the collection being erased? Why does this happen exactly when called `.Cast<T>()`? As far as I know, there are no such problems with other LINQ methods. Is it possible to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe its because the .GetEnumerator() you mocked is not the same instance you access through the default index.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Moq (and not FakeItEasy) when trying to mock PowerPoint's `Shapes` collection.

From what I could gather, it looks like LINQ's `.Cast` calls `GetEnumerator` after casting to IEnumerable interface.

The solution I've found (with Moq) looks like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(f => f.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => enumerator);

// This line makes `.Cast` work
mock.As<IEnumerable>().Setup(f=> f.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => enumerator);
```

Getting back to FakeItEasy, you should modify your fake to also mock `GetEnumerator` on the IEnumerable interface:

```
var fake = A.Fake<IEnumerable>(builder =>
                               builder.Implements(typeof(IFoo)));
var fakeAsIFoo = (IFoo) fake;
A.CallTo(() => fake.GetEnumerator()).Returns(enumerator);
A.CallTo(() => fakeAsIFoo.GetEnumerator()).Returns(enumerator);
fake.DoSomething();
```